# d3.xhr - handling successful empty response

Tags: d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I am making an XHR request with D3:

```
d3.json('/api/A').post('...').on('load', onLoad)
```

However, `onLoad` is never called. The reply is `200 Ok`, Content-Type is `application/json`, body is **empty**.

I suspect that can make a difference as otherwise similar calls work and call the `'load'` handler function.

**Question** is: How to handle this case? How to cleanly distinguish between a `200 Ok` with an empty body and a genuine error?

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty response is invalid JSON (as opposed to an empty object or array, which *would* constitute valid json).

This can be verified using http://jsonlint.com/ or in the console by running `JSON.parse('')`, which throws an error.

So although the response is `200 ok`, the load event — which should only get triggered if the JSON is successfully parsed — *correctly* doesn't trigger in the empty response case.

You could handle this condition via an `.on('error', ...)` listener. Or, you can use the callback options, as in `d3.json('/api/A', function(error, callback) {...})` where `error` is expected to be non-null in this case.

But if you still want to detect the blank string through the "success" rather than "error" path, you could switch to loading the data with d3.xhr instead, and call JSON.parse yourself (you can check out the d3 source to see how that's done). That way, your code can choose to interpret any response however you wish.

Comment: I think it's a case of `JSON.parse('')` and not `JSON.parse(undefined)`, however you're right, that's not a valid JSON

Comment: @PeterV, right, empty string it is. It occurred to me that if you still wanted to detect the blank string but through the "success" rather than "error" path, you could switch to loading the data with d3.xhr instead, and call JSON.parse yourself (you can check out the d3 source to see how that's done). That way, your code can choose to interpret any response however you wish.